# Kotlin maven plugin inner dependencies

Tags: maven, kotlin

I am accessing kotlin libs from offline repository and using kotlin maven plugin. I set the plugin in pom but it creates new dependencies like kotlin-compiler etc. Then I have somebody add this to offline repo and rebuild and this time there is another error saying “this dependency could not be resolved”. So again I need to have somebody add another lib to repo.

But I have lower versions of the corresponding inner libraries but it wants the same version as kotlin-maven-plugin. Can I change that it uses old versions?

(or can I see what dependencies kotlin-maven-plugin brings from a doc or somewhere? I could not find it yet.)

in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.72</version>
    // add sth to make it use with older versions of inner dependencies
    ...
</plugin>
```